# Receive notifications 24/7 via service-worker.js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I've been doing push notifications, 
when I register the page then test it via curl commands, i received the notification!

However after a while (maybe 1-2 minutes), when I close the tab that the push notifications scope has been registered, then test the notifications again, i cant receive the notifications. This usually happens more in google Chrome in mobiles.

The workaround I did in here is that i need to go to the page of the scoped page first, then when I test the notification again, it now works. Though i cant have this because I need the clients to receive notifications without being on the site all the time.

Here are my push event in service worker

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    var SOME_API_ENDPOINT = "https://somewhre.com/push_notification_api/service_worker_endpoint";

    event.waitUntil(
        fetch(SOME_API_ENDPOINT, {
                method: 'post',      
                headers: {  
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
                },  
                body: 'subscription_id=' + subscriptionId
            }).then(function(response) {

            return response.json().then(function(data) {
                var title = data.notification.title;
                var message = data.notification.message;
                var icon = base + "assets/images/logo_notification.png";
                var notificationTag = data.notification.url; 
                // var notificationTag = 'https://google.com'; //data.notification.tag;
                return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                    body: message,
                    icon: icon,
                    tag: notificationTag
                });
            });
        })
    );
});
```

How do i make my service workers 24/7 even though i am not in the page of the scope in the registration of SW?

Do I need to use eventListeners 'install', 'activate' and 'fetch'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service workers appear to persist but really don't - a new instance spins up in response to events. This will be the case when restarting on mobile to handle a push event, but there are also suggestions that busy service workers should allow multiple instances in parallel.

Your `subscriptionId` is a global parameter, so it may well be `undefined` by the time your `push` event fires.

To fix this you need to retain the `subscriptionId` in some kind of storage (mayber IndexedDB).

I also think in order for a service worker to persist it needs to have an `install` event and that event needs to succeed.